# How to create buy one get one promotion in magento

Tags: magento2, coupon

I used Buy X get Y free option.But That promotion is not working.Can any one suggest how to create this coupon.

Comment: Try this https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-cart-buy-x-get-y-free.html

Comment: hi Prathap,Its not working

Comment: Even devdocs isn't working out for you, see BUY 1 GET 1 works like if you add 2 products with matching criteria it cost for only one. That's how the default BOGO works and if you want like BUY X and GET Y isn't available by default as far as I know @Dilip Hope this info useful for you

Comment: Thanks, Prathap

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve these things easily using Shopping cart price rule.

**How Buy X quantity of product, get Y quantity for free works.**

---

The method is creating a product sub-selection and applying the rule providing that the correct number of products from a given field in the cart.

It can be defined that customers will receive Y – an amount of discount if they buy X – the number of products that have been set before. The format of the promotion is “Buy X quantity of product, get Y quantity for free”.

### **How to create shopping cart price rule**

1. Create a Cart Price Rule
2. Define the Conditions
3. Define the Actions
4. Complete the Label
5. Save and Test the Rule

TO get detail description about above points to follow one of the below links to make shopping cart price rule.

- [Mageplaza Blog](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-setup-buy-x-get-y-free-in-magento-2.html)
- [Magneto Devdocs](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-cart-buy-x-get-y-free.html)
- [Magenest Blog](https://store.magenest.com/blog/buy-x-get-y-magento-2/)

I hope it helps!